# Strassen's turnover to brute force

Tags: java, recursion, brute-force, strassen

As a homework assignment over break, our professor asked us to find the point where Strassen's algorithm becomes less efficient than brute force (specifically, how many recursions should I do on this machine before I go to brute force?)

I am in Java, and really struggling to make it revert to brute force. I have a runner class, a brute force class, a class to call Strassen's, and a class for Strassen's itself. As of right now I'm only going to put the Strassen's class up. I ask the user how many recursions they want done, and then I pass that as a parameter into Strassen's. The idea is that, when 'depth' becomes larger than the assigned number of recursions, it calls the brute force method to finish. I'm feeling utterly lost and am probably not approaching this correctly, but we didn't get very clear instructions and I have been trying different approaches all week to no avail.

```
public class strassens
{
    private int totalCalls;
    private int runtime;

    public strassens(int recursions, int runtime) 
    {
        totalCalls = recursions;
        this.runtime = runtime;
    }

    public int[][] strassen(int[][] A, int[][] B, int depth)
    {
        int n = A.length;
        if(depth > totalCalls)
        {
            int[][] complete = new int[A.length][B.length];
            complete = bruteForce.brute(n, A, B, runtime);
            return complete;
        }
        int [][] result = new int[n][n];
        if((n%2 != 0 ) && (n != 1))
        {
            int[][] a1, b1, c1;
            int n1 = n+1;
            a1 = new int[n1][n1];
            b1 = new int[n1][n1];
            c1 = new int[n1][n1];
            for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
                for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
                {
                    a1[i][j] = A[i][j];
                    b1[i][j] = B[i][j];
                }
            c1 = strassen(a1, b1, depth++);
            for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
                for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
                    result[i][j] = c1[i][j];
            return result;
        }
        if(n == 1)
        {
            result[0][0] = A[0][0] * B[0][0];
        }
        else
        {
            int [][] A11 = new int[n/2][n/2];
            int [][] A12 = new int[n/2][n/2];
            int [][] A21 = new int[n/2][n/2];
            int [][] A22 = new int[n/2][n/2];
            int [][] B11 = new int[n/2][n/2];
            int [][] B12 = new int[n/2][n/2];
            int [][] B21 = new int[n/2][n/2];
            int [][] B22 = new int[n/2][n/2];
            divideArray(A, A11, 0 , 0);
            divideArray(A, A12, 0 , n/2);
            divideArray(A, A21, n/2, 0);
            divideArray(A, A22, n/2, n/2);
            divideArray(B, B11, 0 , 0);
            divideArray(B, B12, 0 , n/2);
            divideArray(B, B21, n/2, 0);
            divideArray(B, B22, n/2, n/2);
            int [][] P1 = strassen(addMatrices(A11, A22), addMatrices(B11, B22), depth);
            int [][] P2 = strassen(addMatrices(A21, A22), B11, depth);
            int [][] P3 = strassen(A11, subtractMatrices(B12, B22), depth);
            int [][] P4 = strassen(A22, subtractMatrices(B21, B11), depth);
            int [][] P5 = strassen(addMatrices(A11, A12), B22, depth);
            int [][] P6 = strassen(subtractMatrices(A21, A11), addMatrices(B11, B12), depth);
            int [][] P7 = strassen(subtractMatrices(A12, A22), addMatrices(B21, B22), depth);
            int [][] C11 = addMatrices(subtractMatrices(addMatrices(P1, P4), P5), P7);
            int [][] C12 = addMatrices(P3, P5);
            int [][] C21 = addMatrices(P2, P4);
            int [][] C22 = addMatrices(subtractMatrices(addMatrices(P1, P3), P2), P6);
            copySubArray(C11, result, 0 , 0);
            copySubArray(C12, result, 0 , n/2);
            copySubArray(C21, result, n/2, 0);
            copySubArray(C22, result, n/2, n/2);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public int [][] addMatrices(int [][] A, int [][] B)
    {
        int n = A.length;
        int [][] result = new int[n][n];
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
            for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
                result[i][j] = A[i][j] + B[i][j];
        return result;
    }

    public int [][] subtractMatrices(int [][] A, int [][] B)
    {
        int n = A.length;
        int [][] result = new int[n][n];
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
            for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
                result[i][j] = A[i][j] - B[i][j];
        return result;
    }

    public void divideArray(int[][] parent, int[][] child, int iB, int jB)
    {
        for(int i1 = 0, i2=iB; i1<child.length; i1++, i2++)
            for(int j1 = 0, j2=jB; j1<child.length; j1++, j2++)
            {
                child[i1][j1] = parent[i2][j2];
            }
    }

    public void copySubArray(int[][] child, int[][] parent, int iB, int jB)
    {
        for(int i1 = 0, i2=iB; i1<child.length; i1++, i2++)
            for(int j1 = 0, j2=jB; j1<child.length; j1++, j2++)
            {
                parent[i2][j2] = child[i1][j1];
            }
    }

    public static void printArray(int [][] array)
    {
        int n = array.length;
        System.out.println("Strassens: ");
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 For "trying all week" before coming here (with a somewhat difficult looking problem).

Comment: Not sure I 100% understand the objective, but if you're comparing two matrices using the two algorithms. The efficiency of the Brute force algorithm, I believe, can be calculated the moment you know the size and number of matrices. Therefore you can immediately calculate whether or not your current efforts have exceeded the efficiency of the Brute Force technique. Just make that comparison somewhere within the Strasson's code.